# Elasticsearch query issue1

Tags: elasticsearch

DATA IN ES INDEX:

```
{"qty": 2,"Id": 22,"Classification": "new","price": 10,"orderType": "buy","status": "OPEN"}
{"qty": 2,"Id": 22,"Classification": "old","price": 10,"orderType": "buy","status": "CLOSED"}
{"qty": 4,"Id": 23,"Classification": "new","price": 10,"orderType": "buy","status": "OPEN"}
{"qty": 5,"Id": 24,"Classification": "new","price": 10,"orderType": "buy","status": "OPEN"}
```

I want to write a query to get all records that have classification= 'new' 
BUT if the id is same as an id that has classification old then those docs should not be included in the documents returned by the query

Example :
the following two douments have the same id but one has classification new and one has old so I don want this doc to be returned when i query for all classification new.

```
{"qty": 2,"Id": 22,"Classification": "new","price": 10,"orderType": "buy","status": "OPEN"}
{"qty": 2,"Id": 22,"Classification": "old","price": 10,"orderType": "buy","status": "CLOSED"}
```

Comment: Search time query would be very complex and might not be possible using single query. If it can be found during indexing time that whether the given item has both classification then you can have a field for that and store that info. Say `"hasBothClassification": true` will be present in both docs (one with classification as new and one with old). A document which have only single classification should have `"hasBothClassification": false`. Then you can easily filter out by using this field.

Comment: Another way can be by maintaining a separate index which have a single field against which you keep on adding the ids which have both classification and then you can use terms look up query to filter the documents.